# Safari vs Chrome/Firefox: border-image vs border-color

Tags: css, cross-browser, border-image

Safari treats `border-color:transparent` as overriding `border-image`, whereas the opposite is true in Chrome and Firefox.  (Safari is consistent with the others if `border-color` is an opaque or semitransparent color.  `rgba(0,0,0,0)` behaves the same as `transparent`. I don't know what IE does.)  Concretely, this snippet:

```css
#wrapper { background-color: red; }
#test {
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-image-source: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAkAAAAJAQMAAADaX5RTAAAABlBMVEUA//////+xuF6gAAAACklEQVQIHWPADQAAGwABJwptqgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==");
  border-image-slice: 1 1 1 1;
  background: white;
  background-clip: content-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="test">The border of this box is blue in Chrome and Firefox,
  red in Safari.</div>
</div>
```

draws a light blue border around the `div` in Chrome and Firefox, but a red border in Safari.

Questions:

1. Which behavior is correct?
2. Is there any way to force Safari to behave like Chrome and Firefox?

Note: I've only tested the above example with Safari 10.0 (11602.1.50.0.10), Firefox 48.0.2, and Chrome 53.0.2785.116 (all on OSX 10.11) but the website it's cut down from has exhibited the same behavior consistently for at least a year, so I do not believe this is particularly version-specific.

Note 2: `border-color:transparent` is present for the sake of browsers that don't support `border-image`.  (For instance, I do still care about IE 7 through 10 for the real website this is cut down from.)  Proposed solutions should show the background of the wrapper, not a visible border, in browsers that don't support `border-image`.

Comment: Which version of Safari?

Comment: @Paulie_D 10.0/OSX, but I don't believe this is version-specific - see update

Comment: I just tried testing out this piece of code in both jsFiddle and on a live website (https://www.sats-aarhus.dk/test/).
In both cases, Safari (9.1 (11601.5.17.1)) seems to exhibit same behaviour as Chrome (54.0.2840.98 (64-bit)) and Firefox (50.0) in OSX El Capitan (10.11.4).

Comment: IE is consistent with Chrome and FF. And I think this is the correct behavior ... but it's just a guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you get around that bug:

Instead of

```
border-color:transparent;
```

use

```
border-color:transparent; border-color:initial;
```

As you discovered, Safari does have a bug related to `border-color:transparent`, but adding `border-color:initial` afterwards gets around that bug in Safari, and doesn't cause any additional problems in other browsers that support border-image.

For browsers that don't support border-image (which happens to be just IE <= 10), they happen to also not support the `initial` value there, so they fall back to `border-color:transparent` and you don't get a visible border.

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L78gL7xc/2/

Answer (score 1):

Answers:

#### Answer 1

Behavior with Chrome and FF is correct behavior.

#### Answer 2

Remove `border-color: transparent`.

Or

(Updated answer for IE) use `border-color` (For support check here - [can i use border-color?](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-color))

```css
#wrapper { background-color: red; }
#test {
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image-source: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAkAAAAJAQMAAADaX5RTAAAABlBMVEUA//////+xuF6gAAAACklEQVQIHWPADQAAGwABJwptqgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==");
  border-image-slice: 1 1 1 1;
  background: white;
  background-clip: content-box;
}

#test1 {
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: cyan;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="test">The border of this box is blue in Chrome and Firefox,
  red in Safari.</div>
</div>

<br>

<div id="wrapper1">
  <div id="test1">Simply use border-color, this property is supported effectively in all browsers.</div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you in some way.

Comment: This is helpful, but doesn't 100% solve my problem, because I need the `border-color: transparent` in there for the sake of old browsers that don't support `border-image`.  See the edited question, please.

Comment: @zwol is there some specific reason for you to use `border-color: transparent`?

Comment: Also, do you have a canonical reference (such as a quotation from the relevant CSS specs) to back up the assertion that the Chrome/FF behavior is correct?

Comment: Re 'specific reason', it's probably easiest for me to point you at the real website: https://www.owlfolio.org/ I do not want a solid black bar at the left and top of the main text box in IE 9, which is what I would get without `border-color: transparent`.

Comment: @zwol for backing up answer1: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-image-source. As you are using base64 image with background blue so border-color-should be blue.

Comment: Hmm, a solid blue bar would also look bad.  Really old IE also doesn't support multiple backgrounds and would just get a solid blue background, but versions 9 and 10 *do* support multiple backgrounds, so they'd get the solid blue bar.  I'll have to think about this some more.

Comment: @zwol yeah you can simply use `border-color` as it is support effectively in all browsers - http://caniuse.com/#search=border-color

Comment: I awarded the bounty to the answer with a one-line workaround, but this answer was also very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are accepting as correct other than you need the equivalent for the code shown and has good compatibility..

Personally, I do not code my borders as shown.
So I simply used the borders how I normally would and that seemed to have the light blue border on MacOS Safari, Chrome, FF, iOS 9, Android and IE 8.

```css
#wrapper { background-color: red; }
#test {
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-image-source: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAkAAAAJAQMAAADaX5RTAAAABlBMVEUA//////+xuF6gAAAACklEQVQIHWPADQAAGwABJwptqgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==");
  border-image-slice: 1 1 1 1;
  background: white;
  background-clip: content-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="test">The border of this box is blue in Chrome and Firefox,
  red in Safari.</div>
</div>
```