# Border color of image appears red on Safari

Tags: css, html, macos, safari, drupal-7

Why does the border color of the image turn **red** on *Safari Browser on Mac* but appears **grey**(expected color) on other *non safari* browsers ?  The website I am working on is based on Drupal 7.

Can anyone here explain the reason behind this behavior?

[image]

```
 <style>   
    .img-full-width {
        width: 100%;
        border: solid 1px #cccaca !important;
    }
 </style>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
          <a href="#"><img src=" http://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/language-translation-line-icon-outline-vector-sign-linear-pictogram-vector-id668592940?s=170x170" alt="" class="img-responsive img-full-width"></a>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7">
              <div class="product-pricing product-pricing-min">
                <h6>Random Text</h6>
                <p>From $.1599.00</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-mini shop-now hidden-xs show-sm">Select</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safari vs Chrome/Firefox: border-image vs border-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39704621/safari-vs-chrome-firefox-border-image-vs-border-color)

Comment: Please include your CSS styles relating to the border of the image.

Comment: @Moderator: Accidentally happened to mark this question as a possible duplicate. Need to undo that. Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried set-resetting css properties in css & also using jquery. Also tested the page on safari for windows, and the display was as expected(grey border) instead of red which appears in safari for Mac.

On all other browsers the css works fine. Also the bug wasn't there during the initial release of the site a year ago. So I assume its a bug in Safari-Mac.